# Select count from collection

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to capture the count in a collection table for a certain condition.
For example :

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
BULK COLLECT INTO v_cnt
FROM    tt_product 
WHERE   region = 'NA';
```

The above query throws error saying:

```
   Error(649,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any insights would be highly appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: This link discusses the use of BULK COLLECT.  None of the examples match yours, because your example has an error. http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/bc/

Comment: I understand man . it was a desperate attempt as the normal insert fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove `BULK COLLECT`, you are getting a single value...

Secondly, if I understand you right, and you are talking about the collection of e.g. type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE T AS TABLE OF ...
```

then wrap the name with the `table()` keyword

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_cnt
FROM table(tt_product)
WHERE region = 'NA';
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump your results into a #TEMP table first then do your count from there.

Something like:

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO #TEMP
FROM tt_product
Where region = 'NA'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP
```

This is untested so you might have to play with it a little to get it to work.
My example is for SQL Server, you'll have to find the equivalent for ORACLE as I'm not as familiar with it.

Comment: thanks man . actually, Oracle discourages use of temp tables . so though this might work in mssql, it might not be recommended for oracle

Comment: Sometimes I run into a problem where a temp table cannot be used, in those cases I use a permanent-'temp' table.
Just create a real table that you wipe right before using it. Technically it stays in the database but it's ethereal in nature.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare

  b  l_number := new l_number(1,2,3,4); -- type L_number is table of number ;
  v1 number;
  v2 number;
begin 
 select count(*) into v1 from table(b);
 select CARDINALITY(b) into v2 from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(v1);
dbms_output.put_line(v2);
end;
```